# Is it possible with linux to share a usb hdd via usb and network?

Tags: linux, streaming, dlna

i wonder if its possible with linux (esp raspberry pi) 
to attach my cable TV Receiver to my raspberry (master/slave?) 
that the Cable TV Receiver thinks the raspberry is a hdd 
but at the same time to allow clients in the network to get the recorded movies (for sure not the one which is recording )

I guess the WD-MyCloud *Hardware* is doing the same ?!

```
Linux --USB-- CableTV
 |
 -- USB HDD
 |
 -- Network - Clients
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OwnClod](https://owncloud.org/) lets you access the usb hdd via network, kind of like dropbox. But the raspberry pi's usb has no otg support. So you wont be able to attach the partition to the television trough raspberry pi's usb cable. This is if your TV needs direct access to the HDD.

You could use [Arietta](http://www.acmesystems.it/arietta) or [pcDuino](http://www.linksprite.com/?page_id=815) or any board that supports otg, and use g_mass_storage.

The [g_mass_storage](http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/file_storage.html) lets you take a partition and attach it to the device, the otg-cable is connected to. And the device (TV in your case) would see it as a mass storage.
To attach it you would do something like 'modprobe g_mass_storage file=/dev/sdb stall=0'

If you use Kodi (XBMC) mediacenter, on the Raspberry pi, then you would have access to the files on the mediacenter, and you could use OwnCloud or sambaserver, to access the files on the network.